# network switch/internet modem/router issues

Tags: router, switch, modem

I have a 24 port d-link DGS-1224T and a WD My Net N750 using the Gargoyle router custom firmware.

I want to have my main internet modem connect to my network switch and than from my network switch have a cat6 cord go to the wireless router. but everytime i try to do this I can get internet on the wireless router just via my pc and anything else I connect to my switch directly I would like to know how I can make my router just a wireless access point.

Answer (score 1):

You should [install OpenWRT for your router](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/bridgedap), since [it's unclear if your Gargoyle firmware has the ability to work as a standalone wireless AP](https://www.gargoyle-router.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4605)

Comment: would you be willing to tell me how to set it up as that?